# NFS Performance: Several mounts or mount root directory?

Tags: nfs

Let's say I have the following directories on my main server, each of which is a software RAID5 across four disks.

```
/data/raid1
/data/raid2
/data/raid3
/data/raid4
```

I am going to NFS mount on a number of computers to share access. Is there are performance difference between a single mount of `/data/` vs. individually mounting the RAIDs using four separate mount commands in `/etc/fstab`?